# Trying to pull XML from post with xmlDomDoc.Load (Request) gives useless error

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am creating an asp page to process XML data posted to us by a third party site. I have no control over the sending site at all.

I'm working in classic asp (vbscript) right now just because I'm old school I guess, but I am open to a .net solution as well. Anything that works at this point.

Right now I have the following code:

```
Set objXmlRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDOCUMENT.3.0")

If objXmlRequest.Load (Request) Then
    strLogEntry = strLogEntry & " | XML received"
Else
    strLogEntry = strLogEntry & " | XML failed to load. " & objXmlRequest.parseError.reason
End If
```

When posted to by the third party site, this code puts the following error in the log file:

```
The download of the specified resource has failed.
Error processing resource 'https://blahblah.thirdpartysite.com/xxxx/xxxx-ver2_0.dtd'
```

All attempts at support from the third party site are being handled by a project manager who has absolutely no idea what he's talking about. Still, they are a major handler of these sorts of things and I have to think the problem is on my end.

A quick check of request.servervariables shows that everything seems to be in order as far as the post is concerned.

```
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH: 1120
HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE: text/xml
```

I have found many similar questions but none with working solutions. So, please don't call this a dupe and close it.

Comment: You might want to try setting the [`ProhibitDTD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762632(v=vs.85).aspx) property

Comment: Well, that changed the error message to "XML failed to load. DTD is prohibited."

Comment: Another property you could try is resolveexternals

Comment: That gives me: "XML failed to load. The element 'SomeInfo' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema." That is the top level element.

Comment: OK  sorry I'm out of ideas

Comment: Perhaps you can set `.validateOnParse = False.`

Comment: Ah ha! .validateOnParse = False seems to have worked. If you put that in an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Voodoo, but seems to work around: Disable validation by setting

```
.validateOnParse = False
```