# Why I am Not able to load XML in VBScript?

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript, xml-parsing

I have a XML in a string. When I try to load this XML using `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` object's `Load` method in VBScript, It always returns false, and the XML is valid XML.

Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML>
  jsgdjgs
</cXML>
```

Here is the VBScript code:

```vb
payloadXML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM ""http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd""><cXML>jsgdjgs</cXML>"
Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlLoadSuccess = xmlDoc.load(payloadXML)

If Not xmlLoadSuccess Then
    Response.Write(xmlLoadSuccess)
End If
```

Could anyone guide me what I am doing wrong? By the same method I am able to load XML like this:

```xml
<abc>
<firstName>jgg</firstName>
<lastName>hfgyhg</lastName>
</abc>
```

Comment: Check the MSXML SDK and the default values for the various second level properties, for MSXML 6 you have to explicitly allow DTD and loading of external resources.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks I need to set 
xmlDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", false
    xmlDoc.resolveExternals = false
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = false

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load an XML string. The [`Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722.aspx) method is for loading XML from files. For XML strings use the [`LoadXML()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585.aspx) method:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlLoadSuccess = xmlDoc.LoadXML(payloadXML)
```

Also, for loading XML with a DTD you need to [allow DTDs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2008/10/22/getting-dtd-is-prohibited-from-msxml/) and [disable validation during parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38508214/1630171). I would also recommend enabling synchronous processing.

```vb
Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.SetProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
xmlDoc.ValidateOnParse = False
xmlLoadSuccess = xmlDoc.LoadXML(payloadXML)
```

Note that the return value of the `LoadXML()` method isn't very helpful when debugging, since it doesn't provide any clues about *what* went wrong. Use the [`ParseError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756041.aspx) property to get more helpful information:

```vb
If xmlDoc.ParseError <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "0x" & Hex(xmlDoc.ParseError) & ": " & xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

Comment: I also try LoadXML() but still get the same response i.e false.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just need to send some properties which are:  **xmlDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", false
    xmlDoc.resolveExternals = false
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = false**